# High Charts - Remove the auto shrink the timeframe in x-Axis

Tags: highcharts

Created the Chart with multiple series,1st series having weekly record,other series are having daily record.weekly data starts from Jul-2012.But in the X-Axis time frame,it is auto shrink.How to remove this auto shrink.I want the time frame equally divided.

Comment: any code, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/) ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `dataGrouping`, it's enabled by default.

```
series: [{
    name: 'serie 1',
    data: yourData,
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    }
}]
```

*reference*

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Answer (score 0):

Apart of dataGrouping you can also set ordinal as false.
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal